# Payment Method not showing in magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment

I have enabled the `Cash On Delivery` option in back end. But it's not showing in magento 2 front end. I tried to create back order but it's not showing to me. I checked country too it's for  `All Allowed Country`, but it's not working tell me how to debug and fix.

Comment: check minimum order amount, if you have multiple store then check its setting or post screenshot of cod config so peoples can check

Comment: Find the screenshots https://prnt.sc/gwe9ei, https://prnt.sc/gwe9iw

Comment: I mean screenshot of backend cash on delivery config

Comment: Find here @KeyurShah https://prnt.sc/gweaq4

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean refresh page i think cache issue.

Comment: try to remove minimum order amount value from configuration@JeevaChezhiyan